# How to remove unwanted files in node_modules folder Angular 5

Tags: html, css, angular5

I want to delete the unwanted files in node_modules folder to reduce the size and for fast loading. My application is too slow while loading I don't know what's the reason.Can anyone suggest me to minimize the file size.

Here is my **package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "CoreUI",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
  "description": "Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template",
  "author": "",
  "url": "http://coreui.io",
  "copyright": "Copyright 2017 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.9",
    "angular-split": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "angular2-fontawesome": "^0.9.3",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.2.1",
    "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-ui-switch": "^1.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "chart.piecelabel.js": "^0.10.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "e-ngx-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.6.1",
    "mydaterangepicker": "^4.2.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-drag-drop": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-fancy-image-uploader": "^2.0.1",
    "ng2-split": "^0.1.6",
    "ng2-split-pane": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.6.7",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-quill": "^3.4.0",
    "ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.2",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^1.3.9",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "7.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

I want only dependency files to be present in node modules.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't touch the node_modules folder unless you are confident in what you are doing? It's normal. Usually, node_module folder is a little bit higher in size. It's because It contains the libraries that you are using and their dependencies and their dependencies as well.

Here I can give some suggestions to reduce the Space usage of the node_modules folder

- Try to use Most recent stable versions of the libraries as can as
  possible
- Use a minimum number of libraries. (Don't just Install
  libraries without a purpose)
- If the task is possible to achieve with just vanilla javascript it is not needed to use a library for that.

If you are thinking you have accidentally added packages and removed them by manually editing the package.json file. just delete the entire node_modules directory and run `npm install` or `yarn install`

although the size of the node_module folder is high. they don't have much effect on the performance sake. at the runtime, node knows what codes to execute and what not to execute.

You can find additional information from [this](https://hackernoon.com/whats-really-wrong-with-node-modules-and-why-this-is-your-fault-8ac9fa893823) article.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. I have only minimum number of libraries which i was using. It is mandatory needed libraries. If node_module is not much impact for the performance then  how could i reduce the loading time. In my scenario I have two different projects one is Account module and another is Admin Module. When I redirect from accounts to Admin module ,this module take more time to load which affects our performance. In admin module we have used free base template .Is that a reason for this issue.